# Add new application to Azure Active Directory and configure it's authentication

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create an ARM template to deploy some resources on Azure including an Azure AD application but I can't find a way to add the application using JSON as I can do using the PowerShell cmdlet "New-AzureRmADApplication" also is there is a way to configure the application's manifest file after it's added using PowerShell or JSON?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you want to config application manifest? Just download and update and upload.

Comment: If you want to create a Azure AD app through ARM template?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to automate this, is there is way to download, edit then update this manifest file using PowerShell?